# Echo rows via JOIN in MySQL/PHP (?)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

[image]

I wanna be able to echo out if `Groupname` and `Username`  are connected correctly, where the current `userid` (saved in a session) is `$uid`.

I've been sitting for hours trying all kinds of JOINs and the closest I've gotten is having it output 1/? members for each team, but not all of them.

EDIT:

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM group
        INNER JOIN usergroup ON group.groupid=usergroup.groupid
        WHERE usergroup.userid=$uid";
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $gid = $row['groupid'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user
                 INNER JOIN usergroup ON user.userid=usergroup.userid
                 WHERE usergroup.groupid=$gid";
        $result2=$mysqli->query($sql2);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

        echo "<td>".$row['groupname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row2['username']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['groupid']."</td>";
    }
}
```

Thing is, that it kinda works well, except that it doesn't print all the `groupmembers` names out, it prints out just one. Which one seems to depend on the order in the table.

Comment: please share your code. :)

Comment: Which SQL statements have you tried so far?

Comment: @trincot Edited. Sorry, I'm not as good as I wish I were. I simply wanna echo out all the groups the user is in, and all the members of that particular group.

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly the output you want, but your inner query calls `mysqli_fetch_array()` just once. If multiple rows are expected from that query (as it appears would be the case when a group has more than one member) you will need _another_ while loop inside the first one, like `while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {// output...}`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Well shit. If there's something stalling me, I'll guarantee you it's something quite obvious. Thank you so incredibly much my friend. You've saved my evening.

Answer (score 1):

You did not have a loop on the second query's resultset. However, it is not needed to have a second SQL query. Just do it in one go; SQL was designed for that.

Also, you'll have much simpler code:

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
// Select everything you need in one go (join user table as well)
$sql = "SELECT group.group_id, group.groupname, user.username
        FROM group
        INNER JOIN usergroup ON group.groupid=usergroup.groupid
        INNER JOIN user ON user.userid=usergroup.userid
        WHERE usergroup.userid=$uid";
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);

// Don't need to call mysqli_num_rows if you continue like this:
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>".$row['groupname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['groupid']."</td>";
}
```

Maybe you want to echo some `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags, or you"ll have everything in one row, like:

```
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['groupname']."</td>"
        ."<td>".$row['username']."</td>"
        ."<td>".$row['groupid']."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go: (you were missing nested while loop)

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $gid = $row['groupid'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN usergroup ON user.userid=usergroup.userid WHERE usergroup.groupid=$gid";
        $result2=$mysqli->query($sql2);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0) {
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {    
                echo "<td>".$row['groupname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['groupid']."</td>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Side note:** You could achieve the same results with just one `SQL` query, something like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    usergroup ug
INNER JOIN
    user u ON ug.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY
    ug.id
```

and then in `PHP` (**pseudo code just, do not copy-n-paste**)

```
while($row => mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!isset($groupsWithUsers[$row['groupid']['users'])) {
        $groupsWithUsers[$row['groupid']['users'] = array()
    }
    $groupsWithUsers[$row['groupid']['users'][$row['userid']] = $row;
}
```